# How to setup QGIS Web Client?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

So we've installed QGIS Server and things look to be working well (thanks Underdark for the great tutorial).

Next up we want to get the QGIS Web Client working.  It appears we're missing a step or have misunderstood the instructions at https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client.  How do we get started?  Do we copy the above files to the server and modify the links accordingly?
It looks like the files in the 'site' folder establish a sample website.  Is that what's happening?  And that work together with the Apache config to rewrite URLs in some manner?

I think I can figure this out with just a bit of a nudge in the right direction.

the WMS GetCapabilities link
http://gis.idn12.com/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&map=c:/myprojects/shapefile.qgs&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: This is work: http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG:21781&REQUEST=GetMap&map=C:/OSgeo4W/SERVER/Basel.qgs&BBOX=608350,264875,615466,268677&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=1300&LAYERS=EP&FORMAT=image/png But not the Webclient. I tried also this, but no sucess: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2012-July/020851.html

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and [asked the question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506570/quantumgis-mapserver-and-web-client-can-not-display-standard-helloworld-map-res). As I can see on [your site](http://gis.idn12.com), you hadn't change the pathes in your project.

So, you must **copy** /apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf.tmpl to .../apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf (or rename...but I don't want to risk, so I've just copied it).
Then you must replace all  **<path-to-qgis-server-projects>** in *.../apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf.tmpl* with your real projects path (for example, .../projects).
Then you must copy one of .../site/js/GlobalOptions.js.templ-4326 or .../site/js/GlobalOptions.js.templ-900913 (for SRID=4326 and SRID=900913 projections respectively) to .../site/js/GlobalOptions.js.

And replace all **/home/web/qgis-web-client** entries with your real project path in files:
*.../site/index.html*, *.../site/index.xml.tmpl* (if you will use it...or just in case), *.../site/js/GISProjectListing.js* (this file containts pathes to your HelloWorld and NaturalEarth projects) and in *.../apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf* too.